# STUN server for windows

Tags: windows, nat, sip

Where can I find a STUN server for windows? Open source would be preferred.

Comment: I'm shocked. I have no idea what STUN is?

Comment: @Bart - It's a daemon that helps with SIP NAT traversal.

Comment: http://www.stunserver.org/ leads to http://sourceforge.net/projects/stun/ ?

Comment: @ErikA: So...it's an Enterprise type application?

Comment: I'm stun'ed....

Comment: @ErikA - what sort of Transport does that use?

Comment: Is this something you have implemented all at once or do you phase it in?

Comment: Haha - well played :)

Comment: I have a red sourceforge shirt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Prix suggests, an open-source STUN server for Windows can be found at 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/stun/